# CodeIgniter database check for timeout error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm running a small webservice that gets data from a user specified database, and some of those queries are heavy and often take longer than usual, because those rows contain base64 images and other needed stuff. When my queries take longer than 30 secs CI crashes somehow. I've tried using `$this->db->_error_number()`, `$this->db->_error_message()` and

```
if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
    die('Wops, something weird happened...');
}
```

But none of them gives me error infos. Anybody knows how to capture those timeout errors and echo them to the user? Thanks.

EDIT:

log output:

```
...
DEBUG - 2015-04-10 10:34:34 --> Controller "Main" Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-04-10 10:34:34 --> Helper loaded: log_helper
DEBUG - 2015-04-10 10:34:34 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2015-04-10 10:35:04 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2015-04-10 10:35:04 --> Total execution time: 30.0145
...
```

Comment: Sounds like the maximum execution time of php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Just for testing purposes, I tried setting no time limits with `set_time_limit(0);` but the result is the same.

Comment: Try increasing `memory limit` to a higher value e.g 1024 MB.

Comment: @KamranAdil, you mean in mysql config files? I did this and increased `max_allowed_packet` to a very high value, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 3):

Please check **mysql.connect_timeout** parameter in your phpinfo() and increase in in case require as this may be reason for query timeout.

You can read more about this [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.connect-timeout)

Comment: As I mentioned in @Darius's answer, I tried to changed this value, but I see no diference. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Your query takes too much time. 
If your are using webserver(nginx or apache) hey have default timeout.
In most cases it 30seconds. You can increase timeout time on your webserver.

Also check php timeout parameters in php.ini `max_execution_time`
Or try to `set_time_limit` bigger directly in php code.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` and I also used `set_time_limit()` but nothing changes. The [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) says that `set_time_limit()` doesn't work if `safe mode` is enabled, but in my `php.ini` it is not.